# CodeIgniter optional parameter

Tags: codeigniter, routes

I'm trying to use routing in CI to create a signup form

`signup` is re-routed to `user/signup`

But my signup function can contain a paramater: `function signup($type = 1)`

How can I make this optional via routing? I tried `$route['signup/?(:num)'] = 'user/signup/$1';`, but when going to `/signup` I'm getting a 404, only `/signup/1/` works.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The clearest way to express this would probably be to declare both routes:

```
$route['signup'] = "user/signup";
$route['signup/(:num)'] = "user/signup/$1";
```

Comment: That works fine, didn't think of it, I was trying to figure out how to make it optional. Thanks!

Comment: The edit doesn't seem to work, it doesn't seem to send the parameter with it

Comment: Thanks, I think I prefer your first solution, easier to read / remember.

Comment: @Wesley Thanks! This little tip saved a whole lot of time!

Comment: As of now, 2024, I have this problem, and I just declared both routes. It works like a charm.

Answer (score 24):

For anyone else reading this in due course - I believe the answer should be `$route['signup/?(:num)?']` which makes the number optional as well. I had similar issues on something else.

Answer (score 9):

The trouble with @Ukuser32's answer is that it allows for URIs like signup69 to be accepted, which in this case might be innocuous but in the general case is undesirable.  Just put the slash in with the captured :num

```
$route['signup(/:num)?'] = "user/signup$1"
```

And note that if you have multiple optional segments, then you will need to nest them....