# How to replace product id with product name in url using routing in Codeigniter 3.0

Tags: php, routes, codeigniter-3

This is my URL :https://rentals.in/product/categories/41

Here 41 is the product id and its product name exist in DB is Electronics  so  i want to  convert this URL as  "https://rentals.in/product/categories/Electronics" dynamically using Routing function available in Codeigniter3.0. Is any callback  function can use in routing for achieving above? or  Any Other way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using slugs in codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305786/using-slugs-in-codeigniter)

Answer (score 0):

CodeIgniter follow below routing by default to fetch data by their `id`, if you completely replace the `id` part and search by `name` then there would be chances of getting wrong data, it would give first matching `name`.

```
example.com/class/function/id/
```

**I suggest** you to create Url like this, and make last name part optional

```
rentals.in/product/categories/41/Electronics
```

Which will use `id` to get data and also display `name` of category

Just like SO does. Below both url opens same page.

```
//stackoverflow.com/questions/52051604

//stackoverflow.com/questions/52051604/how-to-replace-product-id-with-product-name-in-url-using-routing-in-codeigniter
```

Refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14183270/2815635)  to make optional param in CodeIgniter routing

Comment: We use URL  like this "rentals.in/product/categories/41/Electronics" and set route as  $route['signup'] = "user/signup";
$route['signup/(:num)'] = "user/signup/$1";  but nothing happens